Audio issue with Ubuntu 24.04
I have recently installed Ubuntu 24.04 on my galaxy book 4 pro.
Everything works fine, but I cannot hear any sounds with my device's audio output.
After some searching, I found out that audio issues with devices using Realtek's alc298 was quite common. I tried the following things;
1. using verbs
https://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?331130-Fixing-ALC298-audio-(no-sound-from-speakers)#google_vignette
2. fixing analog-output-speaker.conf
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TjmHVgCSpQQ
All of these do not seem to work. Plus, I found that my device shows that my audio is working fine. For example, in Pulseaudio, the sound bar is clearly moving but I cannot hear anything.
So does this mean that the OS is sending signals to the speaker but the speaker is not working? Then why do I hear sounds in Windows but cannot in Ubuntu?
Plus, I can hear sound with my headphone.
